# The function of して and のかに

Tags: syntax

I don't really understand what して and のかに mean or their function in the following sentence?

> さあ私がどのようにして友達のマイケルに出会ったのかについてお話しましょう

Comment: It's not のかに but の + か + について.  Also see this link: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-difference-and-usage If you're still stuck then please edit the question to explain your latest understanding.

Answer (score 4):

私がどのようにして友達のマイケルに出会ったのか is "how I met my friend Michael". This is a long noun phrase known as [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010). の before か is a special noun called [explanatory-no](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010).

- どのようにして: how (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17622/5010))

  - どのように: which way / what way
  - して: (by) doing
- 友達のマイケル: my friend Michael
- の: [explanatory-no](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5398/5010)
- か: question marker, forming an embedded question
- ～について: about ～

> さあ[私がどのようにして友達のマイケルに出会ったのか]についてお話しましょう。
> Now, let me talk about [how I met my friend Michael].